# Как корректно расставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Когда практикующий следит за направлением энергии в теле, что это, как не практика осознанного внимания?**

Comment: НЕ практика, не НИ! )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) **Когда практикующий следит за направлением энергии в теле, то что это, как не практика осознанного внимания?**

(2) **Когда практикующий следит за направлением энергии в теле ― что это, как не практика осознанного внимания?**

**Пояснение:**

Это риторический вопрос (он строится по схеме "что это, если это не...).

Постановка тире связана с наличием паузы при пропуске местоимения ***то***.

**Примеры**

Происхождение Вселенной, **что это, как не** большой фокус? [Сергей Носов. Фигурные скобки (2015)]

**Что это, как не** сознательный заговор, направленный на культурную дебилизацию и колонизацию России? [Виктор Пелевин. Любовь к трем цукербринам (2014)]

А прорицание, ясновидение, телепатия, знаменитые „вещие сны “― ч**то это, как не** поток информации, открывшийся из иного, „космического “мира? [А. Е. Рекемчук. Мамонты (2006)]